# Node Red NMEA node not accepting GPS information from Arduino Serial

Tags: arduino, gps, node-red, nmea

Hope you are having a nice day.

My issue is related to a NMEA node not acting properly when I send it GPS information received from an Arduino or Inject function.
It is being sent via serial and has supposedly the correct format.
I tried the same using a VK-162 (USB GPS) and it is working well.
But when I try to send a message with a format like:

$GPGLL,4916.45,N,12311.12,W,225444,A

[image: Inject Function error]

or with the Arduino, I get the following in my debug area:

[image: Arduino error]

If someone could give me some insight I would greatly appreciate it :)

All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a checksum from the end of the line

All of the following work

```
$GPGLL,4916.45,N,12311.12,W,225444,A*31
$GPGLL,5133.81,N,00042.25,W*75
$GPGLL,3751.65,S,14507.36,E*77
```

(checksum calculated with https://nmeachecksum.eqth.net/)

Comment: Thank you so much @hardillb!!!! You were right!! 
Have a wonderful day!